# how to let WCF service to send messages to the client without calling its method from the service?

Tags: c#, wcf, backgroundworker

Im new to WCF and what i know till now that i can use a method from WCF service and it returns some value back, but i was wondering if i used a **backgroundworker** and i want to send a message like "Job Complete" to the client after it got finished, how would i do that? 
Should i use AutoResetEvent and wait for the backgroundworker until completes then `resetEvent.Set()` to let the method on the main thread to return the message?
i need that thread not to get busy, it should be ready for any other commands i request from the client. so any ideas?

Comment: Check out [Duplex Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) that can do something like that. Or then you'd have to check out things like a service bus - your client deposits a request on a bus, the service handles it sometime later, and then sends back another message on the bus to indicate completion.

Comment: @marc_s im using netTcpBinding do i have to change it?

Comment: Yes - Duplex only works with specific bindings, e.g. `WSDualHttpBinding`

Comment: @marc_s i guess tcpBinding is better than http for my winform application, im developing a file explorer that should be fast and sured, umm i still don't know much about the differents, Do you think that i have any chance or someway to keep TCPbinding and let `backgroundworker` to response as i explained in the question?

Comment: If you stick with `netTcpBinding` (which I think is a good idea), then you have basically two options: (1) just accept the request/response pattern - your caller will have to wait until the service completes its work, or then (2) you need to go to a queue--based approach where your client just "deposits" a request into a queue (either MSMQ, or something else) and the service will grab these requests from the queue, complete them, and then send back status messages over a second queue. I don't see what a background worker would benefit you in these scenarios.

Comment: @marc_s it works now, i posted the answer xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out, well i couldn't send message back from service without calling the method but when i changed the attributes of the service behavior from `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single` to `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` it went multithreaded and the result :

 the method runs in a new thread because of this attribute and i can send other request while that thread is working and when it finishs it returns me the message/result.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class FileManagerService : IFileManager
```